# Ocultar varias columnas a la vez de una tabla

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<form>                           
<input type="checkbox" name="col1" checked="checked" !/>Ocultar uno</label><br>
<label id="unId"><input type="checkbox" name="col2" checked="checked" !/> Ocultar dos</label>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
        var index = $(this).attr('name').substr(3);
        index--;

        $('table tr').each(function() {
            $('td:eq(' + index + ')', this).toggle();
            $('th:eq(' + index + ')', this).toggle();
        });
        $('th.' + $(this).attr('name')).toggle();                                                   
    });
});
</script>
```

Funciona perfectamente, me oculta o la primera columna o la segunda de mi tabla pero la pregunta es, ¿puedo ocultar dos columnas con el mismo checkbox? ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?